# Conda: concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install Anaconda on my mac (version 10.9.5).

The command I used:

```
sh Anaconda3-2020.02-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

Led to this error:

```
Unpacking payload ...
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                  
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 483, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 435, in result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
[1061] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

After rooting around, I found [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9125) suggestion, that I check the hash.

I typed this:

```
shasum -a 512 /Users/Slowat/Anaconda3-2020.02-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

and the output was:

```
aa1ed0c40646ba9041abf59c13ce38da1dc51bf15de239b6f966a0b02b4c09c960ae33698c72aa46db41731f8e67938d1972fcb76fa4c5c8081bc0272bb1b535  /Users/Slowat/Anaconda3-2020.02-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

The hash listed [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/hashes/all/) does not match this.

So then I thought it was an issue with downloaded, so i deleted the bash script and the directory that anaconda attempted to make during the failed installation.

I double checked my python version:

```
localhost:~ Slowat$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
```

and re-downloaded Anaconda3-2020.02-MacOSX-x86_64.sh from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual).

I re-checked the hash:

```
aa1ed0c40646ba9041abf59c13ce38da1dc51bf15de239b6f966a0b02b4c09c960ae33698c72aa46db41731f8e67938d1972fcb76fa4c5c8081bc0272bb1b535  /Users/Slowat/Anaconda3-2020.02-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

and it's still wrong. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here (mainly for the original area, checking the hash was just an idea I had).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that conda cannot be run on mac v. 10.9.5; i first updated the mac to 10.11, and then from 10.11 to 10.13 (you have to do it in those two steps). Then conda installed and ran fine.

Comment: I’m not sure if you found it already, but there is some relevant information [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/).

Answer (score 9):

As `marhil95` mentioned in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11703#issuecomment-621922531), you can also get this error if you run out of disk space.

Comment: I have same problem and I dont think this is related to disk space!!!
I have enough disk available, at least I think!